# The role of genus in Tillmann's Surface Operad

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

I suppose my question has two parts.  To begin Tillmann defines the operad $\mathcal{M}$ by its groupoids:
$$\coprod_{g\geq 0} B\mathcal{S}_{g,n,1}$$
In the paper she proves that algebras over this operad are infinite loop spaces.  The fact this operad is, in a way, graded by genus gives me the impression that the $g\leq n$ genus components determine the $n$-fold loop spaces.  Similar to how we define an $E_{\infty}$-operad by the colimit of the $E_n$-algebras.

My question then would be what role is the genus playing here and how?  If I restrict to the genus $0$ case can I use this operad to define $A_{\infty}/E_1$-algebras?  If I restrict to the $g\leq n$ case do I get $E_n$-algebras?  If so I am failing to see how the genus of the surface gives me the homotopy coherent commutativity that I seek.

Comment: The genus $g \le n$ part is not a suboperad so you cannot get $E_n$-algebras like this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct for n=0, but I hear you.  I'm still not sure what the genus is doing for us in regards to generating infinite loop spaces.